# How to properly store the current value of int variable into a token list?

Tags: latex3, token-lists, variable

I have an volatile integer variable (`counter`) and at some point I wish to save its value to a token list (`saved_counter`).
If I save it with just `\tl_set`, as soon as `counter` changes the value, this also changes the value of `saved_counter`, which is undesirable.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_zero_new:N \counter    % Set counter to 0.
\tl_new:N \saved_counter
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
    % Save C_0 in "saved_counter"
    \tl_set:Nn \saved_counter {C \textsubscript {\the\counter}}

    % Print the value of saved counter -> C_0
    \saved_counter

    % Change the value of counter for whatever the reason.
    \int_incr:N \counter

    % Print the value of saved counter again -> C_1
    \saved_counter
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

I understand that there are no real variables in LaTeX and that everything's a macro, therefore, I understand why this is happening.

However, this seems like a common problem and there must be some convenient solution, like expanding/converting the value of `counter` to string and then assigning it to `saved_counter`.
Unfortunately, I am new to LaTeX and couldn't figure it out by myself.

Comment: You don't say, but do we just want the counter value or the 'extras' (the `C`, _etc._). The answer by frougon assumes you do want the extras .... but if you don't, you can save the value directly.

Comment: The same problem occurs when saving just the value. I added 'extras' because those 'extras' are my real use case and I wanted to be sure that offered answers work with it, not just with plain number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your code is that when you do:

```
\tl_set:Nn \saved_counter {C \textsubscript {\the\counter}}
```

the token list variable contains:

- the C character token;
- the `\textsubscript` control sequence token;
- an opening brace character token;
- the `\the` control sequence token;
- the `\counter` control sequence token;
- a closing brace character token.

In particular, `\the\counter` is *not* expanded in your saved token list. It gets expanded later, when you *use* the token list and it is absorbed by TeX token by token. This is why it reflects the value of the counter when your `\saved_counter` is expanded—at the last moment.

The solution is to expand `\the\counter` when you want to save the token list (I used a LaTeX3-ish way to print the counter using decimal notation as with LaTeX2e's `\arabic` or TeX's `\number`):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_zero_new:N \g_my_counter_int    % Set counter to 0.
\tl_new:N \g_my_saved_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \my_update_token_list:n #1
  {
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_my_saved_tl { C \textsubscript {#1} }
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \my_update_token_list:n { x }

\NewDocumentCommand \myUpdateTokenList { m }
  {
    % The x-form eXpands the argument first
    \my_update_token_list:x { \int_to_arabic:n {#1} }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
    % Save the token list using the current counter value -> C_0
    \myUpdateTokenList{\g_my_counter_int}

    % Print the saved token list
    \tl_use:N \g_my_saved_tl

    % Change the counter value for whatever the reason.
    \int_gincr:N \g_my_counter_int

    % This is still the token list saved by \myUpdateTokenList above, where
    % the value 0 had been used.
    \tl_use:N \g_my_saved_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

I also adapted your code to be more LaTeX3-conventional (variable names) and used global incr/set functions for the counter and token list (depends on your application, but is more straightforward this way). I believe it would be cleaner to put `\ExplSyntaxOn` stuff only *inside* the preamble. For this, you'd have to wrap all the LaTeX3 code inside user-oriented commands, as I did for `\myUpdateTokenList`. This makes the LaTeX3 things accessible to LaTeX2e: via arguments passed to commands that you implement in the preamble under `\ExplSyntaxOn` regime.

Comment: I updated my code because `\myUpdateTokenList` was always using `\g_my_counter_int` instead of its argument. Of course, if the same counter should always be used, `\myUpdateTokenList` could be made parameterless and hardcode `\g_my_counter_int` in its definition.

Answer (score 4):

The answer by [frogon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489202) covers the approach best if you want to save not only the value itself but also additional material. There are however other ways.

I would probably just save the value in a second `int`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \counter    % Set counter to 0.
\int_new:N \l__iskustvo_saved_counter_int
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
    % Save C_0 in "saved_counter"
    \int_set_eq:NN \l__iskustvo_saved_counter_int \counter

    % Print the value of saved counter -> C_0
    \int_use:N \l__iskustvo_saved_counter_int

    % Change the value of counter for whatever the reason.
    \int_incr:N \counter

    % Print the value of saved counter again -> C_1
    \int_use:N \l__iskustvo_saved_counter_int
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

If you want to use a `tl`, you can save the value using `V`-type expansion

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \counter    % Set counter to 0.
\tl_new:N \l__iskustvo_saved_counter_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
    % Save C_0 in "saved_counter"
    \tl_set:NV \l__iskustvo_saved_counter_tl \counter

    % Print the value of saved counter -> C_0
    \l__iskustvo_saved_counter_tl

    % Change the value of counter for whatever the reason.
    \int_incr:N \counter

    % Print the value of saved counter again -> C_1
    \l__iskustvo_saved_counter_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```